# About interpolation spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $ (H, \ | \ |) $ and $ (V, \ | \ | _V) $ be two separable Hilbert spaces with $ V $ is injected densely and continuously into $ H $ which is identified with its dual $ H '$ consequently
$$
V \underset{d}{\hookrightarrow} H \approxeq H '\underset{d}{\hookrightarrow}V'
$$
  With $ V'$ \  is \  the \ dual \  of \ $V$.

My question is :
there  is a relation (of embedding for example) between the interpolation space $ [V '; V] _ {1/2; 2} $  and $ H $ in particular ?, and generally between $ [V '; V] _ {1-1 / p; p} $ and $ H $ for $ p> 1 $?   Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you say how you are defining the interpolation spaces?

Comment: $[V′;V]_{1/2;2}$ is a classical real interpolation space as it was defined by Triebel, Hans, in his book "Interpolation theory, function spaces, differential operators", chapter 1.13.